# Not being able to complete this simple calculator exercise. I am getting Nan error

Tags: input, nan, addeventlistener

I am writing a simple code from scratch and I get Nan error in console.log and undefined as a result.

Any suggestion to improve this code will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
<div>

    <h1>Exercises</h1>

    <h4>Items calculator</h4>

    <p>Enter value</p>
    <input type="number" id="numberitems">

    <p>Enter price</p>
    <input type="number" id="priceitems">

    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="pricebtn">Calcular Precio</button>
    <br>
    <p>Resultado</p>

    <span id="finalPrice"></span>


</div>

<script>
    let items = document.getElementById("numberitems");
    let price = document.getElementById("priceitems");
    let finalPrice = items * price;

    const btnprice = document.getElementById("pricebtn");


    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("finalPrice").innerHTML += finalPrice.value;
    }

    btnprice.addEventListener("click", myFunction1);

    console.log(finalPrice);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you are multiplying inputs, not its values.

To get values of input fields, you must get it with `.value` (not `finalPrice.value`)

As second: your price counted at the page loading, not on click event. The result is undefined, because `items` and `price` initializing at page startup, where they yet undefined.

To work it correct, you must getting the values and perform computations in function.

```
<script>
function myFunction1() {
    let items = 0;
    items = document.getElementById("numberitems").value;
    let price = 0;
    price = document.getElementById("priceitems").value;
    let finalPrice = items * price;
    document.getElementById("finalPrice").innerHTML += finalPrice;
    console.log(finalPrice);
}

const btnprice = document.getElementById("pricebtn");
btnprice.addEventListener("click", myFunction1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

let items = document.getElementById("numberitems").value;// ger value from this id
    let price = document.getElementById("priceitems").value; // ger value from this id
    let finalPrice = Number(items*price);

    const btnprice = document.getElementById("pricebtn");


    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("finalPrice").innerHTML += finalPrice;
    }

    btnprice.addEventListener("click", myFunction1);

    console.log(finalPrice);

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, ya he hecho algunos cambios y he logrado hacerlo funcionar.